# Unable to delete document from SOLR using php

Tags: php, solr

I am trying to delete documents based on some attributes. Earlier I was deleting documents from Solr using id as the only field which was working fine.

Now, I have to delete documents based on two fields.
For eg, 
if I have a document :
            {"id":239,"name":"abc", "city":"def"}
I want to delete this document using the following query :

```
http://".SOLRSERVER.":".SOLRPORT."/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Ename%3A".$name"%20AND%20city%3A".$city."%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true";
```

it is similar to:
         `<delete><query>name: $name AND city =$city </query></delete>`

This is working fine on my windows machine but when I am trying to delete from a remove linux machine, it is making no change.

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Quick thoughts on what may be wrong
Mostly stating the obvious to try and rule out possibilities.

- Are you explicitly calling commit operation after delete ? If not then the deleted doc will continue to show till an auto commit happens.
- is there any auto commit interval set. It's likely different between your win dev box and the Linux box.
- before you called delete did you perform a search query for documents with exactly same criteria as the delete call. Just thinking of possibility that the criteria specified aren't enough to pin point the document to be deleted.

Comment: yes @vvs . If you will see my query, at the end there is  commit=true. For your reference, here is another query I am using which is again not working but this time, i am not using "id" as an attribute. http://".SOLRSERVER.":".SOLRPORT."/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3EName:".$Name."%20AND%20Version:".$Version."%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true.          This is working on my local but failed to do anything on linux server.

Comment: Can you dump out the fully-resolved http request that's issued?

Comment: After URL decode your SOLR delete query is 
<delete><query>name:".$name" AND city:".$city."</query></delete>
I can't see anything obviously wrong with your query. 
I suspect that for some reason the query may not be yielding any results. Can you try doing a curl to /solr/select instead of update, but with the same solr query as provided to the delete.